# Await / Not await DisplayAlert

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Xamarin** has awaitable `DisplayAlert` method, so should it be called with await or it can be just called.

In my case I have an `Action`, where `DisplayAlert` should be called. So I have the lambda:

`(a) => { this.DisplayAlert(a.Title, a.Message, a.Cancel); }`

I want to avoid `async` void lambda:

```
async (a) => { await this.DisplayAlert(a.Title, a.Message, a.Cancel); }
```

So without async lambda i cannot await

**What's the best practice?**

Comment: Why do you want to avoid it? Are you okay with using `Result` (synchronous)?

Comment: @Vanna i just try to avoid async lambda http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/

Comment: I guess the async/await pattern used on xamarin methods don't fits on the principle shown at this article you refers. I think this pattern handles the need of to separate proccess you have to do in the UI thread and those you don't... (sorry for the poor english). Maybe [this article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/async_support_overview/) and it's references can lead you the way to best praticles about it.